# How do I make a user generate function to return the sum c()^y and and print each element and the total?

Tags: r

I had to write a R  function  that  will accept a vector input and then raise each element of that vector x to the power of y indicated. But besides that I need to  print each exponentiated  element  and the summed  valued of them .  The sum part I got , but how do I print each exponentiated value as well if the function will only return one object ? HELP please. 
( I had to use for loop as it was specified at the question)

```
sum.power <- function(x,y=2) {    
 n <- c(x)    
 x <- length(n)    
 S <- 0 

 for (i in 1:x){    
   S<-  S+n[i]^y  
 }

 return(S)
}

sum.power (3:10,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't need a loop.  The `^` accepts a `vector` as input.  Once that is done, return multiple outputs as a `list`

```
sum.power <- function(x, y = 2) {
 x1 <- x^y
  list(x1, sum(x1))
}

sum.power(3:10, 5)
#[[1]]
#[1]    243   1024   3125   7776  16807  32768  59049 100000

#[[2]]
#[1] 220792
```

---

If we need to use the OP's, function, create another `vector` for holding the values of the `^` and return a `list`

```
sum.power <- function(x,y=2) {    
 n <- x    
 x <- length(n)    
 S <- 0 
 E <- numeric(x)
 for (i in seq_len(x)){    

   E[i] <- n[i]^y 
   S <-  S+ E[i]
 }

 return(list(E, S))
}

sum.power (3:10,5)
#[[1]]
#[1]    243   1024   3125   7776  16807  32768  59049 100000

#[[2]]
#[1] 220792
```

Comment: @Sathish Yes, I output as a `list` because I thought the OP wanted both

Comment: Thank you so much ,I would love to be able to use the Sum () function , But I cant . The exercise tells me that 1

Comment: @PatriciaTimonerMcManus  Updated the post

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much . I am forever in your debt